# Give the standard matrices

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a question that says...

Let $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by rotating the plane $\pi/2$ counterclockwise; let $S:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by reflecting the plane across the line $x_1 + x_2=0$

A) Give the standard matrices representing $S$ and $T$

B) Give the standard matrix representing $T\circ S$

C) Give the standard matrix representing $S \circ  T$

In A) I've done...

$x=x_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0 
\end{bmatrix} + x_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\1
\end{bmatrix}$

which leads to

$v_{1}=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-1 
\end{bmatrix}\right) $
$v_{2}=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0 
\end{bmatrix}\right) $

so $S=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
 -1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

However, I'm struggling to find $T$. I'm new to linear transformations and I want to make sure I really understand this. So could some please explain/show how you would find the standard matrix for $T$.

Answer (score 1):

In bidimensional case, $\theta$ angle counterclockwise rotation can be written  as:
$$T=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{matrix}\right).$$

When dealing with matrix, composition is just matrix product.